# Passport authenticate function doesn't work

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, passport.js

I'm trying to follow [this](https://medium.com/@robince885/how-to-do-twitter-authentication-with-react-and-restful-api-e525f30c62bb) tutorial to implement the Twitter authentication in my React application.

I've created the script (`user.controller.js`) that handles the *request token* and *authentication* part. Everything works fine, but it seems not every function is called. 
Consequently, on the front-end part, I get this message in console: `POST http://localhost:5000/api/auth/twitter?oauth_verifier=MY-OAUTH-VERIFIER&oauth_token=MY-OAUTH-TOKEN 404 (Not Found)`

Moreover, I'm using `react-twitter-auth` as shown below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import 'bulma/css/bulma.css'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import TwitterLogin from 'react-twitter-auth';

class Header extends Component {
  constructor() {
      super();

      this.state = { isAuthenticated: false, user: null, token: '' };
  }

  onSuccess = (response) => {
    const token = response.headers.get('x-auth-token');
    response.json().then(user => {
      if (token) {
        this.setState({isAuthenticated: true, user: user, token: token});
      }
    });
  };

  onFailed = (error) => {
    alert(error);
  };

  logout = () => {
    this.setState({isAuthenticated: false, token: '', user: null})
  };

  render() {
    let content = !!this.state.isAuthenticated ?
      (
        <div>
          <p>Authenticated</p>
          <div>
            {this.state.user.email}
          </div>
          <div>
            <button onClick={this.logout} className="button" >
              Log out
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      ) :
      (
        <TwitterLogin 
          loginUrl="http://localhost:5000/api/auth/twitter"
          onFailure={this.onFailed} onSuccess={this.onSuccess}
          requestTokenUrl="http://localhost:5000/api/auth/twitter/reverse"
          className="button" />
      );


    return (
      <header className="navbar has-shadow is-spaced">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="navbar-brand">
            <h1 className="title is-4">
              <Link to="#" className="navbar-item">
                <strong>Voting App</strong>
              </Link>
            </h1>
          </div>
          <div className="navbar-end">
            <div className="buttons">
              {content}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
    );
  }
}
```

export default Header;

Here is the `user.controller.js` code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  User = mongoose.model('User'),
  passport = require('passport'),
  express = require('express'),
  jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'),
  expressJwt = require('express-jwt'),
  router = express.Router(),
  cors = require('cors'),
  request = require('request'),
  twitterConfig = require('../twitter.config.js');

var passportConfig = require('../passport');

// setup configuration for twitter login
passportConfig();

var createToken = function(auth) {
  return jwt.sign({
    id: auth.id
  }, 'my-secret',
  {
    expiresIn: 60 * 120
  });
};

var generateToken = function (req, res, next) {
  req.token = createToken(req.auth);
  return next();
};

var sendToken = function (req, res) {
  res.setHeader('x-auth-token', req.token);
  return res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(req.user));
};

module.exports.requestTokenUrl = (req, res) => {
    request.post({
        url: 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token',
        oauth: {
            oauth_callback: "http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F",
            consumer_key: twitterConfig.consumerKey,
            consumer_secret: twitterConfig.consumerSecret
        }
    }, function (err, r, body) {
        if (err) {
            return res.send(500, { message: e.message });
        }

        var jsonStr = '{ "' + body.replace(/&/g, '", "').replace(/=/g, '": "') + '"}';

        res.send(JSON.parse(jsonStr));
    });
};

module.exports.authenticateUser = (req, res, next) => {
  request.post({
    url: 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token?oauth_verifier',
    oauth: {
      consumer_key: twitterConfig.consumerKey,
      consumer_secret: twitterConfig.consumerSecret,
      token: req.query.oauth_token
    },
    form: { oauth_verifier: req.query.oauth_verifier }
  }, function (err, r, body) {
    if (err) {
      return res.send(500, { message: e.message });
    }

    const bodyString = '{ "' + body.replace(/&/g, '", "').replace(/=/g, '": "') + '"}';
    const parsedBody = JSON.parse(bodyString);

    req.body['oauth_token'] = parsedBody.oauth_token;
    req.body['oauth_token_secret'] = parsedBody.oauth_token_secret;
    req.body['user_id'] = parsedBody.user_id;

    next();
  });
}, passport.authenticate('twitter', {session: false}), function(req, res, next) {
      if (!req.user) {
        return res.send(401, 'User Not Authenticated');
      }

      // prepare token for API
      req.auth = {
        id: req.user.id
      };

      return next();
    }, (generateToken, sendToken);

//token handling middleware
var authenticate = expressJwt({
  secret: 'my-secret',
  requestProperty: 'auth',
  getToken: function(req) {
    if (req.headers['x-auth-token']) {
      return req.headers['x-auth-token'];
    }
    return null;
  }
});
```

Here is the router script:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var ctrlUsers = require('../controller/user.controller.js');

router.route('/health-check').get(function(req, res) {
  res.status(200);
  res.send('Hello World');
});

// Routes
router
  .route('/auth/twitter/reverse')
  .post(ctrlUsers.requestTokenUrl);

router
  .route('/auth/twitter')
  .post(ctrlUsers.authenticateUser);

module.exports = router;
```

So my question is: is `passport.authenticate` written correctly? It seems like that function is not called at all. Are there other ways to use it? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

passport.authenticate proceeds to the next callback if the authentication is successful and returns an anauthorized code if it is not.

1.Have you inserted any breakpoints or any logs in any of your callback functions?

2.Are they being called?

3.Is the endpoint being called?

You can have a look at this tutorial for passport authentication as it is very detailed and can guide you through understanding how it works:
http://scottksmith.com/blog/2014/05/02/building-restful-apis-with-node/

Edit:

I can only share with you a piece of code that I have used for basic authentication using passport. It works, but it is not using twitter so you can try it and then modify yours accordingly.

In my auth controller I have this code:

```
const passport = require('passport');
const BasicStrategy = require('passport-http').BasicStrategy;
const User = require('../models/user');

        passport.use(new BasicStrategy(
        function(email, password, callback) {
            User.findOne({ email: email }, function (err, user) {
                if (err) { return callback(err); }

                // No user found with that email
                if (!user) { return callback(null, false); }

                // Make sure the password is correct
                user.verifyPassword(password, function(err, isMatch) {
                    if (err) { return callback(err); }

                    // Password did not match
                    if (!isMatch) { return callback(null, false); }

                    // Success
                   // console.log(user);
                    return callback(null, user);
                });
            });
        }
    ));

exports.isAuthenticated = passport.authenticate(['basic', 'bearer'], { session : false });
```

In my user model I have this function to verify password(you need bcrypt to use it):

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
UserSchema.methods.verifyPassword = function (password, cb) {
    bcrypt.compare(password, this.password, function (err, isMatch) {
        if (err) return cb(err);
        cb(null, isMatch);
    });
};
```

And then in the routes I use it like this:

```
const express = require('express');
let anotherRouter = express.Router();
let anotherController= require('../controllers/another');
let authController = require('../controllers/auth');

anotherRouter.route('/another/route')
  .post(authController.isAuthenticated,anotherController.postSomething);
```

Of course in the isAuthenticated method instead of going to the next Callback you could res.send and end the procedure there instead of calling your next server fuction.

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes, all the endpoints are being called. I also inserted some logs, which are called in every function, except in `passport.authenticate`.

Comment: Do you have other suggestions?